# Getting a link which doesn't have "private"

Tags: swift, url

Both "**documentsUrl**" and "**fileURLs**" below give me paths but different paths.

**documentsUrl** gives "**file:///**var**/**mobile/Containers/Data/Application/595F2B60-A5B4-45CE-ABC9-39624D837F86/Documents/"

**fileURls** gives "**file:///private/var**/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/595F2B60-A5B4-45CE-ABC9-39624D837F86/Documents/Thumbnail_nQY2leifSeMJSKyNCYOYb0TARnZ2/nQY2leifSeMJSKyNCYOYb0TARnZ2-7FD71ABD-DB1C-4F9D-8F21-90D2D22EA271-step-1.MOV"

I need a link, which **doesn't have the "private"** but the **file name** ( nQY2leifSeMJSKyNCYOYb0TARnZ2-7FD71ABD-DB1C-4F9D-8F21-90D2D22EA271-step-1.MOV).

**The link that I want** should look like "file:///var/**mobile/Containers/Data/Application/595F2B60-A5B4-45CE-ABC9-39624D837F86/Documents/nQY2leifSeMJSKyNCYOYb0TARnZ2-7FD71ABD-DB1C-4F9D-8F21-90D2D22EA271-step-1.MOV".

How can I get this?

Please help me.

Thanks

```
 @IBAction func btnDeleteVM(_ sender: Any) {

documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
print(documentsUrl)

            do {
                let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl,
                                                                           includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                                           options: [.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])
                print(fileURLs)
            } catch  {
              print("Error")
          }

}
```

Comment: what does it prints ?

Comment: @jawadAli I figured this out by adding "absoluteURL". Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close, as the OP says the problem has been trivially solved. The question should not be left open to gather dust.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `absoluteURL` didn't work, but what did work was `resolvingSymlinksInPath()`, as in `url.resolvingSymlinksInPath()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).